# I installed a version of Apache newer than what's in the repos. Will it be checked for updates?

Tags: apt, updates, deb

I'm confused about how the package management system works in the case I'm about to describe.  I found similar questions on askubuntu but I don't understand the system well enough to apply what I read to my situation, namely:

I first installed Apache2 version 2.4.7 from the repo.  But, in order to get some advanced [modsecurity](https://www.modsecurity.org/) firewall rules to work, I installed version 2.4.10 by downloading a .deb from the official Ubuntu site at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2.

So, is my system going to automatically check for updates on this package?  I assume I'd get none until if and when the repos are updated to contain 2.4.10.  But maybe I'm wrong about that.

And more importantly, is there a general way to tell by using `apt` if a package is being checked for updates?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update outside of the repositories](http://askubuntu.com/questions/661033/update-outside-of-the-repositories)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will never get updates for manually installed packages, which are not installed by a PPA or by the Ubuntu repositories. You have to download the deb file again and again for each new version.

In your case, you have installed the version for Vivid from the officially Ubuntu Launchpad site. If you start a upgrade to Vivid, you will get updates for your Apache version.