# Update outside of the repositories

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, updates, repository

Let's assume, I have an application (called abc), that is, in the current repositories, on version 1.0 . 
So I find in the internet the news today 'BREAKING: abc Version 1.5 released, IT FIXES EVERYTHING' and everyone goes nuts. Naturally, I want to try.

If I download a deb-file and install abc 1.5 now (and let's assume there are no dependency issues), how will that influence my system, when Version 1.5 or 1.6 comes to the repositories? Will I still be able to normally update with the repositories, or is that software then somehow weirdly 'cut out'?

Weird question, I hope someone understands.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on whether whoever made the package honoured Ubuntu/Debian's versioning of their packages. For example, consider the Vim package:

```
$ apt-cache policy vim
vim:
  Installed: 2:7.4.811-1~ppa1~t
  Candidate: 2:7.4.811-1~ppa1~t
  Version table:
 *** 2:7.4.811-1~ppa1~t 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

If, say, tomorrow Vim 7.5 releases, and somebody makes a package of that with version `7.5` instead of `2:7.5`, it will be "upgraded" to `2:7.4.811-1~...` the next time I upgrade packages in my system.

To explain, a Debian package version has three major fields ([see `man 5 deb-version`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/deb-version.5) for more information):

- the *epoch*
- the *upstream version*
- the *debian revision*

Thus:

```
2:7.4.811-1~ppa1~t
¯ ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯ ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯   
|    |       |
|    |       --- *debian revision*
|    --- *upstream version*
--- *epoch*
```

The *epoch* and the *debian revision* are added by the packagers, and the *upstream version* usually comes from, well, the upstream. If the new package follows any *epoch* that the packages in the repository had, then things should work as expected. The *debian revision* isn't important in this case, since an increase in *upstream version* always trumps it.

Comment: Just to add, when version 7.5 comes to Debian (and then to Ubuntu), it will be versioned at least 2:7.5-1 (as per the Debian versioning policy), so if upstream (the program authors) make a package with version 2:7.5, it will be considered newer than earlier versions, but older than any Debian/Ubuntu version.